# Vaadin Upload control fails silently when user chooses file for which he/she has no read access

Tags: upload, listener, vaadin, file-permissions, silent

I have a vaadin application with an Upload control. The user can browse for a file and upload it using this control, as long as the file permissions on the client side allow reading. If the user chooses a file he or she is not allowed to read, there is no indication anything is wrong when they press the "Upload" button. The server doesn't get notified of an error. I have added Update.SucceededListener, FailedListener, StartedListener, and FinishedListener. No listener is notified of a problem.

Comment: Interesting, does the StartedListener get fired ? Or does the webbroser not do anything? What happens in a normal html uploadform when you select such a read-denied file for upload?

Comment: No, none of the listeners get fired. I put LOG requests in every one, and I see the log messages when the upload works, but if the user doesn't have read permission, no server-side method is called. If there is a way to detect this on the client side, that would be OK too, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: How would I test the "normal html uploadform" on a read-denied file? I have little real experience with html. Should I just create an html file with a form, that contains an upload tag?

Comment: what version of Vaadin are you using? can you show us your upload code?